# Microphone detected but no input (Intel Alderlake Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: sound, microphone

I plugged a wired microphone to the front mic jack on my pc and it shows "microphone (plugged in)  but there is no sound coming out of it.

I also tried to plug the microphone to the motherboard directly (pink input) but no input either.

I searched around and tried multiple solutions but nothing worked so far.

I ran `pacmd list-sources`  and here is the output of that:

```
1 source(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: APPLICATION|IDLE
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6003218000 irq 191"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "7ad0"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

My actual audio is showing USB:

[image: my actual audio is showing USB]

The Intel input is HDMI which I don't use, that plug goes to the monitor which also has speakers, but that's not the one I use.

The microphone works 100%, when it was plugged into the same machine (as Windows) it worked no problem.